# Filling out a table horizontal and vertically with php and mysql

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to PHP so am not sure how to do this.

I have records in a database that link to images (profile pictures) that I want to display 5 along and 4 down. How would I do this?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit?

Comment: Are you trying to generate a table with 5 columns and 4 rows?

Comment: And what if 5 along won't fit? Should the browser display a scrollbar or should they `float` (hint) into a new arrangement? (I'm not trying to complicate things unnecessarily here, just wondering...)

Comment: @MvanGeest Im using percentages for image sizes so they will fit no?
@Anthony Forloney yup that's pretty much what I'm wanting to achieve

Comment: If the only thing you'll display is profile pictures, it's fine (although your data is not tabular and thus a pack of hungry web developers will tear you apart for abusing a table). But if you put text (names etc.) with the pictures, you'll be in trouble soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would find a decent [MySQL Tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/). Then I would practice running some basic `SELECT` queries.

After you've done that it's as simple as

```
$sql = "SELECT `picture_link` FROM `users` WHERE 1";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);

foreach($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->picture_link;
}
```

*Note, this code is generalized*

*General table code*

```
echo "<table><tr>";
$count = 1;
foreach($query->result() as $row)
{
    if($count % 5 == 0)
    {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }

    echo "<td>" . $row->picture_link . "</td>";
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: I know MySQL and SQL, it's just PHP am new too. This would just print them on 1 row each though? not along and down?

Comment: Correct. What you're looking for is a table.

Comment: thanks for adding in the extra code!Looks like it'll do what I want!